# Android DevicePolicyManager locknow() not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I'm locking and unlocked the lock screen.

Unlocking via

boolean result = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword( "", 0 );

devicePolicyManager.lockNow();

In Lollipop, it turns the screen off (expected) and when you turn it
on - instead of the swipe screen - it display the numeric keypad
but you don't have to enter the correct PIN or a PIN to unlock -

This same code works in pre Lollipop by displaying the swipe screen once and 
then fully unlocked after that.

Is this a bug in Lollipop?

Comment: Seems this is a bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78272

Comment: Still not fixed in 5.0.1. Thanks Google!